# log4j info method dont longer work in my spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, log4j

i'm working in a spring mvc web application using spring tools suite, i create a standard spring mvc project at this point log4j was working fine showing INFO information in my console, but now is not longer working it dont show me any type of INFO in my console

i'm using freemarker as my template engine i dont congigured log4j in my web application since it was configured by default

here are my configurations classes

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.abc.app">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

and this is where i call the info method of log4j

```
@Controller
public class LoginControlador {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginControlador .class);


    @RequestMapping(value = "login/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login (Model model) {

        logger.info("this is the login page");
        return "login/login";
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the package name of your class "LoginControlador"?

Comment: package controlador;

Comment: Then it is normal that you don't see logs. The root logger has a "warn" priority so only logs in your class with priority >= WARN will be shown

Comment: but i see the logs before, they just stop showing after a couples o f days

Comment: It is possible only in 2 case: the package name of your class was "com.abc.app" Or the priority of the root logger was < WARN and >= Info.